# How can I use angular-ui/ui-router to dynamically populate a sub view?

Tags: angularjs

I am learning how to use angular-ui/ui-router. So far I have set up the following:

```
var home = {
    name: 'home',
    url: '/home',
    views: {
        'nav-sub': {
            templateUrl: '/Content/app/home/partials/nav-sub.html',
        }
    }
};
var homeOverview = {
    name: 'home.overview',
    parent: 'home',
    url: '/overview',
    views: {
        'grid@': {
            templateUrl: '/Content/app/home/partials/overview.html',
            controller: 'HomeOverviewController',
        }
    }
}
```

This works and shows an overview page that fills my screen.

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x                                                          x
x                                                          x
x                                                          x
x                                                          x
x                                                          x
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Now what I would like to do is to have a dynamically assigned area on this page
that gets content from a database based on the third part of the URL. So that 
a link in my overview page with a URL of /home/overview/1234 would 
get a page and display:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x                                   x                      x
x  Page Links                       x                      x
x                                   x                      x
x  1234                             x                      x
x  12                               x  Page 1234           x
x                                   x                      x
x                                   x                      x
x                                   x                      x
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Can someone suggest how I could do this? I am just looking for
some high level suggestions and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would create a child state for

```
var homeOverview = {
    name: 'home.overview',
    parent: 'home',
    url: '/overview',
    views: {
        'grid@': {
            templateUrl: '/Content/app/home/partials/overview.html',
            controller: 'HomeOverviewController',
        }
    }
}
```

like this

```
var homeOverViewItem={
    name: 'home.overview.item',
    parent: 'home.overview',
    url: '/:id',
    views: {
        'grid@': {
            templateUrl: '/Content/app/home/partials/overviewItem.html',
            controller: 'HomeOverviewItemController',
        }
    }
}
```

In the home view `overview.html` at some place you would define the `ui-view` tag which would get template html inserted from `overviewItem.html`. See some samples here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views

Comment: Thanks. Is there also a way that I could do this by having something like /overview/:id as a URL and then having that available in my controller HomeOverviewController?

Comment: You can try don't declare the last state `home.overview.item`. Update the `home.overview` url to  `url: '/overview/:id'`, i think it should work, but then you should not include `ui-view` inside overview.html